# Python subprocess passes one argument only

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I have a Python script (2.7) which I use to invoke an external process.Till recently it worked fine.

But now when I run it I see it doesn't pass over process arguments.I have also debugged the invoked process and it receives only the single argument (the path of the process executable).

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["./myapp","-p","s"],shell=True)
p.communicate()
```

Execution of the above code passes only "myapp" as the command argument.Why could that happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `shell=True`, just pass a string (not a list);

```
p = subprocess.Popen('./myapp -p s', shell=True)
p.communicate()
```

**Update**

Always prefer;

- `shell=False` (the default) to `shell=True` and pass an array of strings; and
- an absolute path to the executable, not a relative path.

I.e.;

```
with subprocess.Popen(['/path/to/binary', '-p', 's']) as proc:
    stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
```

If you're just interested in the `stdout` (and not the `stderr`), prefer this to the above solution (it's safer and shorter):

```
stdout = subprocess.check_output(['/path/to/binary', '-p', 's'])
```

Comment: Although this is the accepted answer always prefer `shell=False` (i.e. the default). It's far more secure and much more resilient to changes in the program's input, the program's code, and the environment in which it's run. See the Python subprocess documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `shell=True`:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["./myapp","-p","s"])
p.communicate()
```

Comment: Prefer this answer to mine. It's more robust than embedding shell scripts into your Python program. Also, in this instance you probably don't need to invoke a shell.