# Repo command is not running using subprocess

Tags: python

I'm trying to run repo command using subprocess.check_call. I don't see any error but it's not running.

Here is my code.

```
def repo(*args):

    return subprocess.check_call(['repo'] + list(args), shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)


repo('forall','-pc','"','git','merge','--strategy=ours','\${REPO_REMOTE}/branch_name','"','>log.log','2>&1')
```

Am I missing something?

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: I see repo forall -c git reset --hard HEAD was executed properly using subprocess.

Comment: I tried forall -c too. Still having same error.

repo sync , repo forall -c git reset --hard HEAD is working fine, if I pass argument to subprocess.

I think I'm missing something while passing parameter.
Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going on a hunch, I guess you don't see anything because the error messages are stuck in your `stderr` pipe. Try this;

```
import subprocess


def repo(command):
    subprocess.check_call('repo ' + command, shell=True)


repo('forall -pc "git merge --strategy=ours \${REPO_REMOTE}/branch_name" > log.log 2>&1')
```

Does that look more like you imagined? Also;

- when using `shell=True` ([although I don't recommend that your do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24980190/python-subprocess-passes-one-argument-only/24980210#24980210)) you can just pass a `str` (as opposed to a `list`); and
- there is not pressing need for the `return` because `check_call()` either raise an exception or returns `0`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `shell=True` and the first argument a sequence, as you have, then the first element in the sequence will be passed as option `-c` to the shell, and the rest of the elements will be additional arguments *to the shell*. Example

```
subprocess.check_call(['ls', '-l'], shell=True)
```

means the following is run:

```
sh -c "ls" -l
```

Note that `ls` doesn't get the option `-l`, but the shell `sh` does.

So, you should not use `shell=True`. If you have to, use a string instead of a list as `args`.

Also, the [fine manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) warns not to use `stdout=PIPE` and `stderr=PIPE` with `check_call()`.